# How to check if an object is of type IncomingMessage (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, instanceof

I don't know how to make an import of a NodeJS class, to check an object.

Basically I want to do this:

```
if (context.req instanceof IncomingMessage)
```

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import / require the `http` module:

```
const http = require('http')

//

if (context.req instanceof http.IncomingMessage) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `import * as http from 'http';` but I guess that could work also